# Angularjs cache the data and set expiry for httpprovider

Tags: json, angularjs, caching

I am reading json data from web api and binding the data using angularjs. Now i want to cache the json data so that during next request the page will load fast.(There will not be major changes in data frequently.so i can use cached data). But i also want to set the timeout to about 8 hours so that it will read fresh data after 8 hours instead of cached data. i can disable the cache using  `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = '0';` But how to set the cached data expiry time or set it to 8 hours.

Comment: Cache headers are set on server not client.

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways to cache things using the `$httpProvider`.

On way to do it is using a [cachefactory](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) but it doesn't provide a expiration mechanism (even though you can use `$interval` and do it yourself).

Another option is to use a framework which does this. [Angular-cache](http://jmdobry.github.io/angular-cache/) is one example.

BTW, since angularjs is a SPA framework, why would you need an 8 hour cache?